# Invalid location of HTML tag

Tags: java, javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple form using HTML and Servlets. Everything is set, but I am getting a yellow underline in my HTML markup. It says: *Invalid location of tag (input)* , where I am trying to implement the form in my HTML.

My code looks good and I don't see the problem. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Projektuppgift1</title>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    // This is where I am getting the error
    <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
        username: <input type="text" name="name" />
        password: <input type="password" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to be sure. Is this part after </head> tag in <body>, </body> tags?

Comment: body tag and closing html tag is missing^^, Tip: for clean html also use <label for="name">username:</label> for your inputs...

Comment: Anyway, why are you using xhtml strict? Nobody ever really used it (beside fefe) and its html5 in 2015... build code for the future, not for yesterday...

Comment: I think he uses it because it is the default for JSP, as it heavily relies on XML. (Still a bad idea though)

Comment: oh, I did not see the jsp tag. Should upgrade to JSF 2.2 to have html5 support then and use components instead of plain html.

Comment: You can use html5 with plain JSP too. IMHO JSF is also a dead end in the future.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with Java and even less with JavaScript. The question is purely about HTML syntax, except for some specific type of reporting errors in some coding environment.

Answer (score 4):

The `form` tag may only contain block elements is XHTML Strict, so neither `<span>` nor `<input>` is valid. You can wrap it in a `<div>` though, then it is fine.

For example:

```
<form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
    <div>Username: <input type="text" name="name" /></div>
    <div>Password: <input type="password" name="password" /></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="submit" /></div>
</form>
```

However I would advise against using XHTML, it is a thing of the past, and has some serious drawbacks too (e.g. IE8 does not support it at all, and unfortunately some people still have to use this). You should use HTML5, it also has an XML serialization.

Comment: xhtml strict is so 2004 ... we are html5 in 2015, and you should use <fieldset> and <label> instead of <div> and <span> in your form...

Comment: There are no problems with IE when using XHTML *unless* you serve XHTML documents with an XML content type (which is rarely done and would seldom have any good reason). Besides, HTML5 in XML serialization *is* (one version of) XHTML.